# nodejs - Getting 401 error trying to download docs revisions with Google Drive API export links

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I need to download all the revisions of a google doc with the Drive API using nodejs but I don't understand how to authorize the request for the export links. Once I get the export link for each revision I call:

```
var options = {
           url: 'https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=1DRl6rbcVuuLVyb_WlhBLiYiCByWcS2bKGlLIsn7E8_8&revision=1&exportFormat=txt', //example link
           method: 'GET',
           headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${jwToken}`, 
            },
           }
request(options).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(mydownloadfilename));
```

where the "jwToken" is the token I use to get the revisions list so I guess it should be still valid. However, with this I get the 401-Unauthorized page. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I would start here it explains how to work with the authorization https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/nodejs   Then go to this https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads#node.js which explains download

Answer (score 0):

According to the Drive API v3 [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-revisions#list-revisions):

> Revisions for Google Docs, Sheets, and Slides **can't be downloaded.**

So essentially, if the actual revision you want to retrieve is the file itself, then the method above is the correct one.

As for the authorization part, you will need to perform the **Node.js Quickstart** from [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/nodejs) and follow the steps explained there.

Since you want to export the file, you will just need to modify the code and add this part:

```
function downloadDoc() {
   var fileId = 'ID_OF_THE_DOC';
   var dest = fs.createWriteStream('DESTINATION_OF_THE_OUTPUT_STREAM');
   drive.files.export({
     fileId: fileId,
     mimeType: 'application/vnd.google-apps.document'
   })
       .on('end', function () {
         console.log('Done');
       })
       .on('error', function (err) {
         console.log('Error during download', err);
       })
       .pipe(dest);
}
```

#### Reference

- [Drive API v3 - Manage Revisions](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-revisions);
- [Drive API v3 - Files:export](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/export);
- [Drive API v3 - Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/nodejs);
- [Drive API v3 - Download a document](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads#download_a_google_document).

Comment: Thank you for you reply. I was aware of that note on the api reference but the export links which I obtain from revisions.list actually work if I paste them into a browser in which I am logged into the correct google account, so I don't understand what is the difference between this and calling it from code with request().

Comment: What scopes are you using for your request? @user13840873

Answer (score 0):

I am facing this same problem. The solution is to use

1. OAUTH2 authorization for a user that has Edit or Owner permissions for a file
2. Get an access token that expires quickly
3. call the V2 URI (V3 does not work) for the file/rev to get "export links" 3) Call the correct export link for your format type
4. then you will get a randomized temporary redirect link from Google that you can then call to get the binary stream.

This is a great starting point for C# .NET -- [windows oauth console app](https://github.com/googlesamples/oauth-apps-for-windows), if you want working code to do steps 1 and 2. I posted a working [v2 code function here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66465017/how-can-i-download-a-revision-of-a-google-doc-using-drive-api-3-0) that you can put into the console app example.