# How can I download a Revision of a Google Doc using Drive API 3.0?

Tags: google-drive-api

I finally have a working solution for Drive API 2.0 (v2) in c# .NET to get a Google Doc Revision binary stream using the process below. This process for getting a Document Revision is very different from just getting a normal Document.

**To get a Google Doc Revision in v2**

1. OAUTH2 authorization (the account used must have Editor permissions)
2. Send GET request to version 2 of the Drive API with the FileId and RevId (this returns Revision metadata)
3. Send another GET request to version 2 of the Drive API with "export" URI obtained in step 2 for the desired export type, such as docx (or pdf/etc), for the Revision (this returns a massively long URI that expires quickly).
4. Send another GET request to the temporary "export" URI to get the binary file stream of the Revision and export type specified in step 2.

Is there a way to get the binary stream of a Google Doc Revision in Drive 3.0 (v3)? This feature seems to have been removed. C# or JavaScript or curl or PHP or any coding language is fine...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your issue. Can't you just download the desired `exportLink` returned in step 2? I'm not aware of any changes between v2 and v3 which are relevant to your current situation. Can you provide the relevant parts of the code you're working on?

Comment: Yes, I can download the returned links, but only if I use a V2 URI. The V3 URI returns no links. I added a code sample.

Comment: The only reason I went down this path of writing 300+ lines of code is because the Drive API does not allow this in v2 or v3---> driveService.Files.Export(fileId, mimeType, revID); It makes no sense why Google would not just give access to Revisions in the normal API (v2 or v3). Instead I have to go back to v2 and make an authorized GET request to a URI which then gives a redirect link.

Comment: If anyone wants to try this out, use this awesome console app in C# https://github.com/googlesamples/oauth-apps-for-windows

Comment: `The V3 URI returns no links` That's not what I'm experiencing. I get `exportLinks` for v3. Have you tried this via [Try this API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions/get)? Do you get the same behaviour?

Comment: Ah yes, I found that in V3 I have to specify "fields" with "exportLinks". But none of that matters, actually, since I am developing a backend integration with no user interface. I actually can figure out the links but then I must re-authenticate with OAUTH2 in a web UI to get the binary stream of the Revision Link.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! No answers in the question, please. I have rolled back/edited your question and removed the answer. Add the answer in the answer section only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution to get a Revision from a Google Doc that is secured. Note: The user in the OAUTH2 flow must have Edit permissions on the doc. This uses a [front end solution](https://github.com/googlesamples/oauth-apps-for-windows) with the modification below.

```
   private async Task GetRevisionStream(string accessToken, string fileId, string revId)
    {
        Log("Making API Call to get revision binary stream...");

        // builds the  request
        string userinfoRequestUri = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=" + fileId + "&revision=" + revId + "&exportFormat=docx";

        // sends the request
        HttpWebRequest userinfoRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(userinfoRequestUri);
        userinfoRequest.Method = "GET";
        userinfoRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: Bearer {0}", accessToken));
        userinfoRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        userinfoRequest.Accept = "Accept=text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";

        // gets the response
        WebResponse userinfoResponse = await userinfoRequest.GetResponseAsync();
        using (StreamReader userinfoResponseReader = new StreamReader(userinfoResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            // reads response body
            System.IO.Stream streamDoc = userinfoResponseReader.BaseStream;
            var fileStream = File.Create("d:\\test.docx");
            streamDoc.CopyTo(fileStream);
            fileStream.Flush();
            fileStream.Close();
        }
    }
```